# I can't run the Android Emulator

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, environment-variables, android-sdk-2.3, android-sdk-manager

I'm completely new to Android and Android Studio. I was just coding. 
So I was running the previous version of Android Emulator and it worked perfectly fine.

1. However, when I downloaded the latest Android Emulator 27.1.12, my Emulator couldn't run properly. 

   **Issue:** The code is running fine, but the Emulator can't display my application. When I click on the Emulator screen, I can still hear the Audio of my app. So I think the problem would be with my computer's hardware.
2. Because the Emulator couldn't run, I uninstalled the Android Emulator 27.1.12 and Android Studio reported these errors:

   **Issue:**

   > 08:32  Emulator: [6684]:ERROR:android/android-emu/android/qt/qt_setup.cpp:28:Qt library not found at C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\lib64\qt\lib
   >   08:32  Emulator: Could not launch ‘C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator/qemu/windows-x86_64/qemu-system-i386.exe’: No such file or directory.

So, when I install the Emulator, it crashes, when I un-install it, I encounter these 2 errors. So is there a way for me to use the Emulator without causing the 2 errors?

Answer (score 0):

I see in the new update of Android Studio, the `Android Emulator` option is not enabled by default.
So, let enable it in the `Settings` as the bellow and run `Android Emulator` again.

[image: enable emulator enable]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure from your question, whether or not you have uninstalled and reinstalled the AVD Manager, so in the case you haven't:

I suggest you completely **uninstall** and then **reinstall** the **Android Virtual Devices SDK (AVD Manager)**.

You can use the following instructions to help you out:

To uninstall/install the AVD Manager, go to **Tools > SDK Manager > Android SDK** and select the **SDK Tools** Tab. Then scroll down until you find the Android AVD/Virtual Devices SDK.

Also, make sure that the **Android Emulator SDK is also installed**.

Answer (score 0):

Have Android 3.2.1 which you need to install emulator manually by going into 
Tools > SDK Manager > Android SDK and then select the SDK Tools Tab. Check the 'Android Emulator' then Apply.