# Android emulator won't start something not found

Tags: android-emulator

Android emulator won't start something not found:

```
21:40   Emulator: [4748]:ERROR:android/android-emu/android/qt/qt_setup.cpp:28:Qt library not found at C:\Android\android-sdk\emulator\lib64\qt\lib

21:40   Emulator: Could not launch 'C:\Android\android-sdk\emulator/qemu/windows-x86_64/qemu-system-aarch64.exe': No such file or directory

21:40   Emulator: Process finished with exit code 2

21:41   Emulator: [1456]:ERROR:android/android-emu/android/qt/qt_setup.cpp:28:Qt library not found at C:\Android\android-sdk\emulator\lib64\qt\lib

21:41   Emulator: Could not launch 'C:\Android\android-sdk\emulator/qemu/windows-x86_64/qemu-system-aarch64.exe': No such file or directory

21:41   Emulator: Process finished with exit code 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I have gone to this issue and enable `Android Emulator` option in the Android Studio will fix it.
Could it help!

[I can't run the Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49269184/i-cant-run-the-android-emulator/51946073#51946073)

Answer (score 0):

From your question I noticed the following error log:

```
21:41   Emulator: [1456]:ERROR:android/android-emu/android/qt/qt_setup.cpp:28:Qt library not found at C:\Android\android-sdk\emulator\lib64\qt\lib

21:41   Emulator: Could not launch 'C:\Android\android-sdk\emulator/qemu/windows-x86_64/qemu-system-aarch64.exe': No such file or directory
```

This tells us that there is an issue with your Android Virtual Devices SDK.

I suggest you completely **uninstall** and then **reinstall** the **Android Virtual Devices SDK (AVD Manager)**.

You can use the following instructions to help you out:

To uninstall/install the AVD Manager, go to **Tools > SDK Manager > Android SDK** and select the **SDK Tools** Tab. Then scroll down until you find the Android AVD/Virtual Devices SDK.